# i need help in adding facebook share into my ios application

Tags: swift, sdk

i am trying to add facebook share dialog into my ios application and i found the official page from facebook on how to do it, but i run into a problem about ContentProtocol. i dont know what that is. here is the link to the guidence that i use . it is pretty straight forward. basically just install the pod facebookshare, import it and add few line of code, but i got problem on `'myContent'`

here is the code 
import FacebookShare

```
let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
shareDialog.mode = .Native
shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
shareDialog.completion = { result in 
  // Handle share results
}

try shareDialog.show()
```

here is the link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/share-dialog

what should i put in the myContent?

Answer (score 1):

I guess next link is explained what you can use as *content* and how to use it
[Content-types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/content-types)

*(From documentation)* Currently, the Facebook SDK for Swift can share 4 different kinds of `content`:

- **Links** - Represented by the `LinkShareContent` object.
- **Photos** - Represented by the `PhotoShareContent` object.
- **Videos** - Represented by the `VideoShareContent` object.
- **Open Graph** - Represented by the `OpenGraphShareContent` object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FBSDKShareLinkContent

```
let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "//URL")
content.contentTitle = "MyApp"
content.contentDescription = "//Desc"
content.imageURL = NSURL(string:"//Image URL")
```

Comment: and content.contentTitle is a get-only property